# calling a php function with exec()

Tags: php, exec

I am trying to use exec() to run and pass parameters to a php function named new_array() in array_module.php and expect an array return but having no luck. using the format:

```
$cmd = exec('cd "c:/wamp/www/test_array" && php array_module.php "'.$input['first'].'" 
     "'.$input['second'].'" ');
```

Any   help  is appreciated

Comment: Why `exec`?! Why not `require_once 'array_module.php'; $result = someFunc($input);` like a sane person?

Comment: apologies new to using php in CLI

Comment: and could you elaborate please? what can i wrap the require_once 'array_module.php'; $result = someFunc($input); in?

Answer (score 0):

Don't make a call through the command line to another file. **Import** the other file so its functions become available and simply **call** the function directly:

```
require_once 'c:/wamp/www/test_array/array_module.php';

$result = new_array($input['first'], $input['second']);
```

This assumes that `array_module.php` is written in a sane way so it can be imported elsewhere of course, e.g.:

```
<?php

function new_array($one, $two) {
    ...
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately have to run the function in the background

Comment: What does that mean, "background"? Why?

Comment: It is to be run parallel to another function as a cron job called using CLI

Comment: `exec` wouldn't run anything "in parallel" to begin with. There are many question on SO how to run things in parallel using PHP, look at those first.